# Laravel 5.2: Event when a cache expires

Tags: php, laravel

Is there an event we can use when a cache is about to be expire? My plan is to write the data to db before it expires. There are currently 4 events but I don't think neither of them does this.

Also, when are the cache events `missed` and `hit` called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no event for expiration. In most cases, Laravel has no involvement in expiration beyond setting an expiration time when the data is stored. The underlying system (Redis, memcached, APC, etc.) handles the actual expiration independently.

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Respository.php` has the various situations `missed` and `hit` events occur for (search it for `fireCacheEvent` calls). Any call that requests data from the cache (`Cache::get`, `Cache::remember`, etc.) and doesn't find it is a miss. If data is retrieved from cache, it's a hit.

As an example, the `Cache::get` call:

```
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    if (is_array($key)) {
        return $this->many($key);
    }

    $value = $this->store->get($this->itemKey($key));

    if (is_null($value)) {
        $this->fireCacheEvent('missed', [$key]);

        $value = value($default);
    } else {
        $this->fireCacheEvent('hit', [$key, $value]);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: I see. How does this sound, what if I create a cache as `Cache::forever()` then forcibly forget it every 24 hrs writing it to db. Once someone needs it again and it doesn't exist (deleted by cron), it queries the db and the whole process repeats all over again. I'm doing this because I'll be migrating servers in a few months and I want to make sure I have all the data. Does that make sense at all?

Comment: @enchance I've done stuff like that. As an example, we had a counter for the number of entries in a day, and a cron that'd run the next day to save that tally to the database. Works well, as long as you can handle losing it occasionally - Redis is *very* reliable but it's still possible for the server to go down or restart, losing the count.